# Problem with http request when using git hub pages

Tags: angular, https, github-pages

I just uploaded my angular project to git hub pages https://igalachourov.github.io/, now when i run it locally the http request work just fine, but when I launch through github pages it says

"Mixed Content: The page at  'xxxxxxxxx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'xxxxxxxxxx' This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

I saw a guide that says to click the shield icon with the x on him and click "Load unsafe scripts" and it worked, but its no good for the hr team at the company I try to join, they asked me to fix it .

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

For the internals app calls, you can try to implement an interceptor to ensure all calls are https:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class EnsureHttpsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // clone request and replace 'http://' with 'https://' at the same time
    const secureReq = req.clone({
      url: req.url.replace('http://', 'https://')
    });
    // send the cloned, "secure" request to the next handler.
    return next.handle(secureReq);
  }
}
```

For the static files, you should avoid to explicitly set http or https, just serve it with double slash

```
//domain.com/myimage.png
//domain.com/style.css
```

If the static file can't be served over https you can disable from github page the ensure https option.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because your site is deployed in a `https` url provider but your code somewhere points to a `http` url. Check if your application consists of urls in any file (including the `index.html`) with `http` url providers and replace them with `https`.

Also there are somethings you need to consider while deploying

1. In your GitHub pages repo settings, be sure that you have checked
   the **Enforce HTTPS option**
2. Always provide your
   `--base-href` with a `https` prefix rather than a `http`.

Example:

```
ng build --prod --base-href "https://user_name.github.io/test-app/"
```

You can read more in the [official documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https)